# Opening a new tab in Chrome makes all bluetooth devices disconnected

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bluetooth

I have an issue using the following versions

Chrome 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

When I open a new tab, sometimes all my bluetooth devices (headphones, mouse, keyboard) become disconnected. They come back in ~5 minutes, resetting devices or the bluetooth module doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the voice search ("OK Google")

When a user opens a new tab, Chrome sometimes tries to access microphone to use voice search which breaks bluetooth connectivity.

Resolution:

Go to [chrome://flags/](http://chrome://flags/) and disable option **"Enable Voice Search on the local NTP"**

Answer (score 0):

Experience this issue after macOS Ventura update but it could've happened to anyone depending on the Handoff configuration. If you're using an Apple device, try this:

Go to  **System Setting** > **General** > **Airdrop & Handoff** and ensure this is all turned off.

If it doesn't work, try other troubleshooting but this did work for me.

[image: Screenshot of the 'Airdrop & Handoff' settings]